# Changing Default Python env.(from 2.7 to 3.3) in Anaconda on Mac OS 10.8

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, osx-mountain-lion, anaconda

I have the Anaconda distribution installed for Mac. I have Mac OSX 10.8 (Mountain lion). The problem I don't often use Anaconda is because the default Python which it uses is 2.7 while I work on 3.3 or atleast prefer to work on that.

I really like the Spyder IDE of Anaconda. Is there a way I can get the default environment on Anaconda changed to 3.3 instead of 2.7 so that Spyder and iPython all use 3.3 default?

I see the following help from Anaconda site:

```
$ conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda

Here python=3 and anaconda are package specifications, and it is the job of the SAT solver inside conda to find a consistent set of packages which satisfies these requirements. As the root environment uses Python 2, we had to specify the major version explicitly.

After adding the binary directory of the newly created environment to the PATH environment variable, which may be done using

$ source activate py3k
```

My question is I have separately installed Python 3.3 and associated Scientific Python packages like Pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn etc using Homebrew so that it doesn't conflict with my Mac OS default Python 2.7. So now if I run the above Conda commands in Mac Terminal will it interfere with other Python packages I have installed using Homebrew? or will it automatically install/upgrade the python and other packages in the Anaconda library without interfering with either the Homebrew installed Python or Mac OS default Python?

Please advise.

Comment: Just make sure to `source activate` the python that you want, and you should be fine. You can always tell which python is "active" at a terminal with `which python` (or `which conda`, `which pip`).

Comment: @TomAugspurger how to `source activate` particular python version ?

Comment: The conda environment will have a `bin` folder with an `activate` script inside it. so you want `source <ENV NAME>/bin/activate`

Answer (score 2):

No, the Homebrew and Anaconda Pythons will stay completely independent of one another. Just make sure you don't have `PYTHONPATH` set, which causes this to not be true.

Also, you should know that Spyder is not available for Python 3 in Anaconda yet, because PySide has not yet been built for Python 3.

Comment: Update: Spyder is already available for Python 3 in Anaconda. I am using it with 3.4

Answer (score 0):

I had installed Anaconda with python 2.7, but even after adding python3:

> conda create --name Py3 python=3

spyder continued to call python2.7

creating an environment with BOTH spyder and python=3 worked for me:

> conda create --name SpyPy3 python=3 spyder